# AVL tree balance factor

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree class, I want to find balance factor of each node ( `balance_factor: node->Left_child->height - node->right_Child->height` )

Here is my code:

```
int tree::findBalanceFactor(node p){
    int a;
    if( p.lchild)   p.lchild->balance_factor=findBalanceFactor( *p.lchild );    
    if( p.rchild)   p.rchild->balance_factor=findBalanceFactor( *p.rchild );

    if( p.rchild && p.lchild )          a=p.balance_factor = p.lchild->height - p.rchild->height ;
    if( p.rchild && !p.lchild )         a=p.balance_factor = 0 - p.rchild->height;
    if( !p.rchild && p.lchild )         a=p.balance_factor = p.lchild->height;
    if( !p.rchild && !p.lchild )        a=p.balance_factor = 0;

    cout << "md" << a << endl;
    return a;
}
```

In the main function when I print `root->balance_factor` it shows me always number zero `balance_factor` is a public variable and in the constructor I assigned zero to that.

What is the wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *much* simpler way to do this than testing every permutation of lchild and rchild:

```
int tree::findBalanceFactor(node &n) {
    int lheight = 0; 
    int rheight = 0;

    if (n.lchild) {
        findBalanceFactor(*n.lchild);
        lheight = n.lchild->height;
    }
    if (n.rchild) {
        findBalanceFactor(*n.rchild);
        rheight = n.rchild->height;
    }
    n.balance_factor = lheight - rheight;
    std::cout << "md " << n.balance_factor << std::endl;
    return n.balance_factor;
}
```

Since this otherwise seems to have ended up as an all-code answer, I'll add a brief note on *how* to get from the original code to this.

On one level, it's trivial to observe that each of the four branches in the original has the same form `(left - right)`, but with `left=0` whenever `lchild` is null, and `right=0` whenever `rchild` is null.

More broadly, it's really useful to look for this kind of pattern (ie, that each branch has essentially the same expression).  Writing out truth tables or otherwise partitioning your state space on paper, can help clarify these patterns in more complex code.

You should always aim to know what the general case is - whether because you implemented that first, or because you were able to factor it back out of several specific cases. Often implementing the general case will be good enough anyway, as well as being the easiest version of the logic to understand.

If the general case isn't good enough for some reason, then being easy to understand means it is still a good comment, as it provides a point of comparison for the special cases you actually implement.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the reason why the `balance_factor` of the root node is always 0 because of these 2 lines of code in the `tree::findBalanceFactor` method:

```
if( p.lchild)   p.lchild->balance_factor=findBalanceFactor( *p.lchild );    
if( p.rchild)   p.rchild->balance_factor=findBalanceFactor( *p.rchild );
```

I suppose that the `node` struct/class looks something like this:

```
struct node {
    struct node *lchild;
    struct node *rchild;
    int balance_factor;
    int height;
};
```

What happens in `findBalanceFactor( *p.lchild )` and `findBalanceFactor( *p.rchild )` is that, we are passing **new copies** of `p.lchild` and `p.rchild` into `findBalanceFactor` (as seen from the pointer dereference), and hence the `balance_factor` attribute of the original `p.lchild` and `p.rchild` are not updated.

The solution will be to modify the `tree::findBalanceFactor` method to take in **pointers to node**, like this (I've taken the liberty to prettify the code a little):

```
int tree::findBalanceFactor(node *p) {
    int a;
    if (p->lchild) {
        findBalanceFactor(p->lchild);
    }
    if (p->rchild) {
        findBalanceFactor(p->rchild);
    }

    if (p->rchild && p->lchild) {
        a = p->balance_factor = p->lchild->height - p->rchild->height;
    } else if (p->rchild && !p->lchild) {
        a = p->balance_factor = 0 - p->rchild->height;
    } else if (!p->rchild && p->lchild) {
        a = p->balance_factor = p->lchild->height;
    } else {
        // this is the case for !p->rchild && !p->lchild
        a = p->balance_factor = 0;
    }

    cout << "md" << a << endl;
    return a;
}
```

For `p->lchild` and `p->rchild`, we do not need to set their `balance_factor` another time, since the `balance_factor` of each `node` is already set in one of the 4 possible cases of the very long `if` statement.